# Wiring Transition from Inside of wall to Outside of Wall for hard-wired appliance

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance

I am installing an electric kickspace/toe kick heater as part of my kitchen remodel.  I do not quite understand how to transition the supply wiring from inside the wall to the space underneath of the cabinet where the heater will located.

It seems if I used a junction box that is secured inside of the wall (like all standard receptacle/switch installations), there would not be a way to get the wire into the living space (requirement for the junction box to be closed up with a faceplate).

If I mount a junction box outside of the wall, so I can use the side entrances/exits for the wires in the living space, then the supply wire would just exit the wall unprotected for a small distance - I don't think that is code compliant (please correct me if I am wrong).

Any advice would be helpful.  NEC 2014 applies in my area and the work will be inspected.

Comment: Can you give us a model number for the heater?

Comment: As @ThreePhaseEel points out this can't be properly answers without the heater model number.  It's likely the required junction box is built into the heater.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the space under the cabinets is inaccessible and would be treated like the interior of a wall.

In that case, you could merely cut a hole in the wall at the back bottom of the cabinet that will hold the heater and continue your cabling into the opening that will hold the heater.

Once the cable is attached to the heater and the heater is pushed into the opening, the cable is protected.

Access to connections by removing a fixture is generally considered code compliant.